# How do I define the Queue size of Objects in Java (Queue Data Structure)

Tags: java

I thought I did the correct implementation for reference type to only present 6 objects that can only be stored in a queue, however I am getting an issue where my code literally adds more than 6 objects in a queue even though it has gone past the limit. Therefore, are there any good examples of setting the size of a queue (reference type - objects). Otherwise here is my example of the queue implementation thus far: Yes I know I can just use the java utility package but that defeats the objective...

```
// Queue uses class List.
package student_finance;

public class Queue <T> 
{
   private List<T> queueList;
   private int capacity; 

   // no-argument constructor
   public Queue() 
   { 
      queueList = new List<>("queue"); 
      capacity = 1;
   } // end Queue no-argument constructor

   // add object to queue
   public void enqueue(T object)
   { 
      queueList.insertAtFront(object); 
      capacity++;
   } // end method enqueue

   // remove object from queue
   public T dequeue() throws EmptyListException
   { 
      return queueList.removeFromFront(); 
   } // end method dequeue

   // Another way of Capacity = Capacity - 1;
   public void Decrement() 
   { 
       capacity--;
   }

   // Returns the size of the Queue currently. 
   public int Size() 
   { 
       return capacity; 
   }

   // determine if queue is empty
   public boolean isEmpty()
   {
      return queueList.isEmpty();
   } // end method isEmpty

   // output queue contents
   public void print()
   {
      queueList.print();
   } // end method print
}
```

Comment: At least, you have to fix all compilation problem: i.e. `queueList = new List<>("queue");`

Comment: as part of `dequeue()` method you need to decrement capacity as well, also you need to have another variable which will store upper limit of queue, which can be inserted in constructor, enqueue() should check `if(size==capacity)` then do not insert it in to queue, same way while dequeue() check `if(capacity==0)` do not dequeue.

Comment: Sounds very good to me dkb Thank you all for the support and love :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your queue appears to actually be a stack. You're enqueuing and dequeuing from the same end of the list, making it LIFO, rather than FIFO.

```
  queueList.insertAtFront(object);
```

and

```
  return queueList.removeFromFront();
```

Secondly, nowhere do you actually specify the limit of your queue, so there's nothing to stop more than 6 elements being enqueued. You need to check within `enqueue` that you haven't reached your limit - if you haven't, then continue to enqueue.

Comment: Oh my god thank you I didnt even know that the implementations were freak wrong thank you ben for clarifying that with me, I need to now sort that